# Samsung galaxy S3 continuously downloading on gprs

Tags: downloading, gprs

My mother in laws phone continuously downloads from GPRS, seemingly even when wifi is available.  Usually the downloads are very small and in multiples over a short period.  occasionally they are much larger, up to 50MB.

The records from the provider indicate that some of these downloads are from Facebook and youtube, however she has not used these apps or logged in.

The downloads are occurring so often that she is getting warnings that she will exceed her quota (200MB/month).

She has set apps so they don't update automatically. Also she syncs three gmail accounts to the phone.

Does anyone know what these frequent downloads may be, and also if it is possible to limit them to only when wifi is available.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If she does not use GPRS, then best is to disable mobile data usage

But if you do not want to completely disable GPRS, then here is an article which shows how can you limit mobile data usage.
[disable or limit mobile data usage](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/02/13/how-to-disable-mobile-data-usage-beginners-guide/)

here are couple of apps to monitor and control you mobile data usage
[control mobile data app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sigterm)

Comment: i also had similar problem, but now i will definately use this android app for mobile data monitoring and excess usage